# Change numbers format in arabtex

Tags: fonts, arabic, arabtex

I would get Arabic numbering within `arabtex` environment  defined from `arabtex` package to write arabic sentences.

If I insert numbers 1,2,3,.... inside `arabtex` environment I get indian form ١,٢,٣,....

I know I can just type `\LR{1,2,3,...}`,but I would like to get it automatically without inserting it inside `\LR` every time, also with format of counters like `\thepage`.

I suspect this has to do with the font `nash` which define the format of numbers, any suggestion

**Update**

I use `pdflatex` to compile my document

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}

\begin{document}

\setcode{utf8}

\begin{arabtex}
\huge 1 2 3 
\end{arabtex}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}


\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\chardef\CharNormal=0
\chardef\CharBound=255
\newXeTeXintercharclass\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`0=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`1=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`2=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`3=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`4=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`5=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`6=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`7=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`8=\CharNumbers
\XeTeXcharclass`9=\CharNumbers
\newtoks\TokSetfont
\TokSetfont={\begin{normalfont}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharNormal\CharNumbers=\TokSetfont
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharBound\CharNumbers=\TokSetfont
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharNumbers\CharNormal={\end{normalfont}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks\CharNumbers\CharBound={\end{normalfont}}


\begin{document}

\setcode{utf8}

\begin{arabtex}
\huge 1 hello 2 3 345 
\end{arabtex}

\end{document}
```

Inspired by [this answer](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=20600).

Here is the result...

[image]

### UPDATE WITH PDFLATEX

The following solution is compatible with pdflatex, based on the `l3regex` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}



\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_substituteNumbers_tl
\cs_new:Npn \substituteNumbers #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_substituteNumbers_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {[0-9]+} {  \c{LR}\cB {\0 \cE}  } \l_substituteNumbers_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_substituteNumbers_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\substituteNumbers{%
\begin{arabtex}%
\huge 1 hello 2 3 345 
\end{arabtex}%
}%

\end{document}
```

And this is what you get:

[image]

I hope that this solution fix your problem!

### UPDATE 2: Enumeration fixed

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}



\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_substituteNumbers_tl
\cs_new:Npn \substituteNumbers #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_substituteNumbers_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {[0-9]+} {  \c{LR}\cB {\0 \cE}  } \l_substituteNumbers_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_substituteNumbers_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\LR{\arabic{enumi}}}


\begin{document}

\substituteNumbers{%
\begin{arabtex}%
\huge 1 hello 2 3 345 

\begin{enumerate}
\item A 1
\item B 2
\item C 3
\item D 4
\item E 5
\end{enumerate}

\end{arabtex}%
}%

\end{document}
```

In this version, enumerate environment uses arabic numbers, as required by @salim bou. The result of the previous code is shown in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PieCot your code resolve the problem well with `xelatex`, but I need to compile my code with `pdflatex` Is there a possibility for that ?

Comment: I've updated the answer ;)

Comment: How about format of conters like `enumi`, I still get indian format of numbers inside `enumerate` environment, sorry because I did not made this clear in my question. I want all apearance of numbers will be on arabic form.

Comment: Updated for enumerate environment.