# Change numbers form automatically

Tags: pdftex, characters, arabic

I have posted a question [Change numbers format in arabtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306085/change-numbers-format-in-arabtex)
I'm trying to use the solution  provided by PiCot and it is not working  (years ago it was working fine) !?

I need numbers to appears in maghrib form 0 1 2 ...
and it look like that used arabic font do not contain those form of numbers so how can I do an automatic substitution from a font which contain those form of digits ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{expl3}

 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_sun_tl
\cs_new:Npn \sun #1{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_sun_tl{#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {[0-9]+}{ \c{textLR}\cB{\0 \cE} } \l_sun_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_sun_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{عنوان} 
    
1 2 3

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The macro `\sun` does only work on its argument, so you have to actually use it on your numbers. Also, it's better to define the front-facing macro with `\NewDocumentCommand` (if you don't want this, you should define `\sun` with `\cs_new_protected:Npn \sun #1`, as it needs to do assignments and hence should be defined protected).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{expl3}

 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_sun_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \sun { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_sun_tl{#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN {[0-9]+}{ \c{textLR}\cB{\0 \cE} } \l_sun_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_sun_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{عنوان} 
    
\sun{1 2 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the linked question I need to change every occurence of degits 1 2 3 ... to show arabic form not ١ ٢ ٣ ....  is there  an automatic way to do this without inserting numbers as command argument every time ?

Comment: @SalimBou it certainly might be possible, but I don't know a way to do that in a reliable and fool-proof way, manually markup is the more reliable way to go here. You could search through your document with this regular expression and do a regex-replacement in your editor to ease the process.